# Trying to implement signIn in NextAuth in Next.js, but using separate frontend and backend projects, essentially separating client and server code

Tags: javascript, web, next.js, next-auth

I am aware that this does not seem sound, especially given that NextAuth is supposed to provide client-side authentication.

But I'm in a situation where I am required to test a repo with NextAuth, but I can't migrate my original code yet. This results in the workflow to separate the code into repos for client and server, yet still using NextAuth on both repos.

I am currently trying to implement the `signIn()` method in the client side and get the credentials from the server side, but the signIn flow is always trying to access the api from the same domain where the `signIn()` method launches.

ie. Client is on `http://localhost:3010` and I expect it to connect to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/` but instead it attempts to connect to `http://localhost:3010/api/auth/`.

I saw that I can configure environment variables to specify different routes such as `NEXTAUTH_URL` and `NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL` but I'm unsure if these modify the parameters I need to make it work how I need it to work...